# Aligning text in Org-mode after refactoring or making changes

Tags: org-mode, align

I use org-mode mainly to write extensive notes, but I'm finding it difficult to "justify" while refactoring or making changes.

For example, suppose I have to make changes to the following text:

```
* Heading

  A line of nearly 80 characters that ends with newline character
  remaining part of the line
```

If I've to add few words in first line (after heading), then the text will look like

```
* Heading

  A line of nearly 80 characters (plus some random stuff in brackets)
  that ends with newline character
  remaining part of the line
```

But ideally, I want something like

```
* Heading

  A line of nearly 80 characters (plus some random stuff in brackets)
  that ends with newline character remaining part of the line
```

Is there some way in which I can automate this "justification" using org-mode?

Comment: `M-q` while in the paragraph with misaligned text? Or are you looking to do that automatically for the whole file?

Comment: @wvxvw I wasn't aware of `fill-paragraph`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requirement can be solved by using`M-q` or `M-x fill-current-paragraph`.
Refer [GNU Emacs Manual: Explicit Fill Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fill-Commands.html).

Comment: There is also `org-fill-paragraph` that also aligns tables and such.

Answer (score 1):

If you add to your org hook, you won't have to keep manually calling M-q.

```
     (add-hook 'org-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                              (visual-line-mode)
                              (org-indent-mode)))
```